# woocommerce not able to generate new API Key - JS error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to generate new API Keys in latest woocommerce plugin to use for REST API. But there is an error on woocommerce >> settings >> API >> Generate Key button and that not getting submitted.

So, How to get rid of this error and how to get my consumer and secret key.

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: @zarex360 please see the screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/i1jn7j)

Comment: @JBoulhous both latest chrome and firefox not working.

Comment: I would say, it's probably an issue loading javascript files, probably jquery file, try deactivating your plugins and use a default theme to detect what causes this issue. it's almost always the case.

Comment: Nope, It's not worked even after disabling enabling the plugin @JBoulhous

Comment: All i can say is that jQuery is not loader, would you check that ? would you check also if Backbone and underscore are loaded, basically resolve the console errors. to dig more you should use `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` file to load non minified javascript files.

Comment: Resolved, Just by commenting the code at line no. 31 and set return true [link](http://prntscr.com/i1pp1z)
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/api-keys.js?ver=3.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, Just by commenting the code at line no. 31 and set "return true" in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/api-keys.js?v‌​er=3.2.6
[see the code](https://prnt.sc/i1pp1z)

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed one plugin that make conflict for you deactive some plugins that you don't need and test again.