# Problem in Generating API key in woocommerce site for REST api

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to generate API Key for REST API from WooCommerce site.

I am following below steps-

```
Step 1- WooCommerce->Setting->REST API
Step 2- Click on 'ADD KEY' button
Step 3- Enter details like description, user and permissions with read/write access
Step 4- Click on 'Generate API KEY' button
```

After Click on 'Generate API KEY' button, I am seeing never ending loader. Hence unable to see consumer key and secret to use in my application for syncing activity.
But when I open same WooCommerce site in another tab then I found API key (with only last few alpha numeric key) has been generated although In first tab still loader is appearing.

I am not getting why screen having key and secret with bar code is not appearing and only never ending loader appear.

Same steps I performed for another WooCommerce site and I can see key and secret along with bar code. I didn't figure out so far whats going wrong with this WooCommerce site. I tried to disable all plugins and follow answer in [woocommerce not able to generate new API Key - JS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282061/woocommerce-not-able-to-generate-new-api-key-js-error)

But it didn't work for me.

Any help and suggestion is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

There might me some javascript issue, you can always check the api key and secret in your database

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_api_keys`
```